# HighCharts Axis Label Encoding

Tags: highcharts

I have a system using the HighCharts chart and seem to be getting a problem displaying some UTF characters, the display is fine in IE but Chrome and Firefox don't display the characters correctly.

In the VB code, we are building up a javascript function to label the bar chart.

```
sb.AppendLine("   xAxis: {")
sb.AppendLine("       title: {")
sb.AppendFormat(" text: '{0}'", JSEncode(Server.HtmlEncode("Planificación Mes Período")))
sb.AppendLine("       },")
```

In IE it displays correctly as 
Planificación Mes Período

but in chrome and firefox it displays as below with & before the #

> Planificaci #243;n Mes Per #237;odo

We need to HtmlEncode the text to prevent any addition HTML being run for security reasons, I've looked into using a RegEx to remove any HTML tags instead of the HTML encode but it didn't work as we wanted.

I'm just confused why it works fine in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Have you set charset in your site to UTF-8? Simple example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/101/

Comment: We've changed it to not HtmlEncode the text.

Italic and Bold tags work on the text but links and buttons don't appear which is OK for us security wise.

Comment: You don't need to HtmlEncode JSON. You also don't need the escape sequences. Just use the plain original UTF-8 character as you see it! The only thing you need to do is to declare the content as being UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have a related issue and stumbled across your question here.  The reason is that IE properly interprets the HTML encoded data because HighCharts renders the chart in IE using HTML.  In FireFox and Chrome, it renders it using SVG so the HTML encoded data isn't interpretted as, well HTML ... For example, I have an issue where one of my data labels includes an ampersand ('&').  If I HTMLEncode my label, the '&' in the string is encoded as & and IE renders it perfectly.  Chrome/FF do not ... the literally render '&'.  If I remove HTML encoding, Chrome/FF display '&' but IE does not render the label as it get's hung up on interpretting the '&' as the start of an HTML encoded character.

Sorry this isn't an answer per se, but wanted to have this documented somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

In RFC 4627 in chapter 3 it says:

"*JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode. The default encoding is UTF-8.*"

==> this means that you don't need to encode anything when you are using UTF-8 anyways (in your Java IDE?).

And further down it says:

"*JSON may be represented using UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.  When JSON
 is written in UTF-8, JSON is 8bit compatible.  When JSON is
 written in UTF-16 or UTF-32, the binary content-transfer-encoding
 must be used.*"

If you encounter problems with special characters while transfering data for Highcharts from the server to the client, then try to check your http header. It should be like this:

```
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Otherwise make sure that the JS file that is used to configure highcharts is saved as UTF-8.

If you still feel the need that you must encode character then apply chapter 2.5 of the RFC:

*If the character is in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that encode the character’s code point. The hexadecimal letters A though F can be upper or lowercase. So, for example, a string containing only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as “\u005C”.*

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

Judging the RFC this is perfect JSON:

```
sb.AppendFormat("text: 'Planificación Mes Período'");
```